# Calculating net migration using survey data in R

Tags: r, migration, survey, standard-error

In R, if I use the svytotal function from the [survey](http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/) package to produce an estimate and standard error for the number of people who migrate from one county to each of several others and then use the same function for migration in the opposite direction, how can I calculate the net migration and corresponding standard errors? Here is how I'm calculating migration in a single direction from [IPUMS](https://usa.ipums.org/usa/) data:

```
mig_count_left=as.data.frame(svytotal(~nowpuma,design=subset(pums_design,left==1)))
```

*nowpuma* is a factor with the name of the place a person currently lives. *left* equals 1 when the person has been identified as having left his/her previous county. Result looks like this:

```
                                                                  total         SE
nowpumaAllegany & Garrett Counties                                  342  134.08951
nowpumaAnne Arundel County                                         2132  851.19956
nowpumaBaltimore County                                            5473 1153.62968
etc...
```

I am hoping for something like:

```
in_out_df=merge(mig_count_left,mig_count_entered,by=row.names) #put in & out migration in a single dataframe
in_out_df$net=in_out_df$total_left-in_out_df$total_entered #compute net
in_out_df$net_SE=????   #calculate standard error for the net migration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you just write a loop with the code i already gave you to compute this for all pumas?

```
# loop through one puma at a time
for ( asp in all.state.pumas ){

    pums_design <- 
        update( 
            pums_design , 
            this.net.migration = 
                ifelse( nowpuma == asp & prevpuma != asp , -1 ,
                ifelse( prevpuma == asp & nowpuma != asp , 1 ,
                0 ) )
        )

    # compute in-migration, out-migration, and net migration for the current puma
    # with all standard errors
    out <-
        svytotal( 
            ~ as.numeric( nowpuma == asp & prevpuma != asp ) +
            as.numeric( prevpuma == asp & nowpuma != asp  ) +
            this.net.migration , 
            pums_design 
        )

    # stack `out` with all the other pumas
}
```

Comment: Thank you Anthony. I've edited the question to include the style of code I am hoping for. The result would be a dataframe with all counties, in migration, out migration, net migration, and all related standard errors.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I thought I could calculate the point estimate with simple arithmetic and then rely on a survey package specific function to compute the standard error. I appreciate your approach.